# Adding bank account to customer (balanced payment api)

Tags: python, balanced-payments

I am trying to add bank account to customer. But I am getting following error.

`Bad Request: 400: Invalid field [card_uri] - "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP29J5STPtZVvnjAFndM0N62/bank_accounts/BA7bk9dLT3My3fhAmZejgrKq" does not resolve to card Your request id is .....`

Bank account successfully added.

`Python Code`:

```
customer = balanced.Customer().save()
customer.add_card('/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP29J5STPtZVvnjAFndM0N62/bank_accounts/BA7bk9dLT3My3fhAmZejgrKq')
```

Javascript init

```
/balanced.init('/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP29J5STPtZVvnjAFndM0N62/',{'debug': true});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that:

> /v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP29J5STPtZVvnjAFndM0N62/bank_accounts/BA7bk9dLT3My3fhAmZejgrKq" does not resolve to card

You're doing a:

```
customer.add_card('/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP29J5STPtZVvnjAFndM0N62/bank_accounts/BA7bk9dLT3My3fhAmZejgrKq')
```

You should do this instead:

```
customer.add_bank_account('/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP29J5STPtZVvnjAFndM0N62/bank_accounts/BA7bk9dLT3My3fhAmZejgrKq')
```